# Error installing iOS 6 sdk Documentation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

When I go to:

**Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads**

I have the following screen:

[image]

I am having the following error, after I it has downloaded the `iOS 6.0 Library`:

> Installation path,
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset,
>   points to a folder that does not look like a valid documentation set
>   for updating.

What could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Xcode 4.5 (4G182) downloaded and installed using App Store, refers to the docs as a Documentation Set, not a library:

> iOS 6.0 Documentation Set (v. 41.39)

which has a higher version number than your iOS 6.0 Library.

[image]

Comment: Downloaded yesterday the Xcode from the App Store, so it's a bit strange

Comment: Could you please give me the feed of the documentation? So I could add it manually.

Comment: iOS 6.0 Documentation Set (v. 41.39) 
API reference and conceptual documentation for iOS 6.0. 
Copyright © 2012 Apple Inc. All rights reserved. 
Feed: http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone6.0.atom 
Web Root URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/cc8a92/ 
Identifier: com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary